# Unable to show image in 2nd activity from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have some images in drawable and have a listview. I want to click the image in listview and open that image fully in another activity. I have complete listview but unable to show full image.
activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </ListView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

list_single.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <TableRow>
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

CustomList.java

```
 package learn2crack.customlistview;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
   public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
     private final Activity context;
      private final String[] web;
      private final Integer[] imageId;
      public CustomList(Activity context,
   String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
     super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
  }
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
     View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
     TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
     txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
     imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
     return rowView;
   }
 }
```

MainActivity.java

```
 package learn2crack.customlistview;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import android.app.Activity;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  ListView list;
  String[] web = {"Nature1", "Nature2","Nature3","Nature4","Nature5","Nature6","Nature7" } ;
  Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7 };
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
   list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
   list.setAdapter(adapter);
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // I am using this way to show image in another activity
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
  });
 }
  }
```

full_image.xml

```
 <?xml version =" 1.0 "encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
    Xmlns:android = " http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android : layout_height="match_parent"
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fullImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <LinearLayout/>
```

FullImage.java

```
 package learn2crack.customlistview;
  import android.app.Activity; 
  import android.os.Bundle; 
   public class FullImage extends Activity {
    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
     }
   }
```

Kindly suggest me why I am unable to show image in this fullimage class.

Comment: You didn't even set the image in `ImageView`...so how will you see the image in the `FullImage` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..
In MainActivity- onItemClick

add this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",imageId[position]);
                startActivity(intent);
```

and in fullImage class add these lines after setContentView.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fullImage);

        int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("image",0);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the name of image clicked through the intent that you are using to start the 2nd activity which you can take and set appropriate image on the imageView in the 2nd activity.

To send the data through intent you can use 
`intent.putExtra(name,value)`
And in 2nd activity you can use the `intent.getStringExtra(name)` to get that name sent from the 1st activity and then set the corresponding image on the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that is - You need pass image name form activity1 to activity2 whatever you select . You can do this resources object with puteExtra then you can get string or any other thing in form of key-value pair. You are getting this issue because your imageview references doesn't pass to another activity